# PostgreSQL Exporter for docker - Prometheus

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm, prometheus

I have been reading this page for years, and now I need some help.
I m starting to configure Prometheus to collect metrics from Docker Swarm and Docker containers, It works really good with cAdvisor and Node Exporter, but now i m having issues to collect metrics from PostgreSQL docker container. I m using this exporter --> https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
This is the service in docker-compose.yml:

```
postgresql-exporter:
  image: wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
  ports:
    - 9187:9187
  networks:
    - backend
  environment:
    - DATA_SOURCE_NAME=postgresql://example:<password>@localhost:5432/example?sslmode=disable
```

And this is in prometheus.yml

```
  - job_name: 'postgresql-exporter'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['postgresql-exporter:9187']
```

We have two stacks, one with the db and the other one with the monitoring stack.

Logs in the postgresql service:

```
monitoring_postgresql-exporter.1.krslcea4hz20@master1.xxx.com    | time="2019-11-02T16:12:20Z" level=error msg="Error opening connection to database (postgresql://example:PASSWORD_REMOVED@localhost:5432/example?sslmode=disable): dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused" source="postgres_exporter.go:1403"

monitoring_postgresql-exporter.1.krslcea4hz20@master1.xxx.com    | time="2019-11-02T16:12:29Z" level=info msg="Established new database connection to \"localhost:5432\"." source="postgres_exporter.go:814"

monitoring_postgresql-exporter.1.krslcea4hz20@master1.xxx.com    | time="2019-11-02T16:12:30Z" level=info msg="Established new database connection to \"localhost:5432\"." source="postgres_exporter.go:814"

monitoring_postgresql-exporter.1.krslcea4hz20@master1.xxx.com    | time="2019-11-02T16:12:32Z" level=info msg="Established new database connection to \"localhost:5432\"." source="postgres_exporter.go:814"

monitoring_postgresql-exporter.1.krslcea4hz20@master1.xxx.com    | time="2019-11-02T16:12:35Z" level=error msg=**"Error opening connection to database (postgresql://example:PASSWORD_REMOVED@localhost:5432/example?sslmode=disable): dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused" source="postgres_exporter.go:1403"**
```

But when I look in prometheus targets section, the postresql-exporter endpoint says is "UP"
And when I check the pg_up metric it says 0, no conection.
Any idea of how can I solve this?
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Here is the config of postgreSQL docker service db:

```
  pg:
    image: registry.xxx.com:443/pg:201908221000
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=example
      - POSTGRES_USER=example
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - allnet
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
```

Thanks

Comment: Endpoint `up` means Prometheus is able to scrape the exporter. `pg_up == 0` means the exporter is not able to connect of Postgres. How is the Postgres configured ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Hi! Thanks for answering, I updated the answer with the config.
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use 'localhost' to talk from one docker container to the other. You need to use the host name of the other container (the container name by default).
Use this url: postgresql://...@pg:5432/...